# Узнать режим базы данных firebird при помощи запроса

Tags: firebird

Доброе время суток!

Столкнулся с проблемой, что необходимо узнать mode базы данных, находится она в режиме read_only или read_write.

Знаю, что это можно узнать из databaseinfo, передав ей подключение, но проблема в том, что это нужно узнать на уровне хранимой процедуры. Вроде перерыл все служебные таблицы, ничего не нашёл.

Спасибо заранее за подсказку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел сам.

```
select mon$read_only from mon$database
```